# SAPUI5 IconTabBar/IconTabFilter dynamically building

Tags: sapui5

I am very new to SAPUI5 and think the IconTabBar/IconTabFilter could help me with a page I am creating. I am not sure I can do what I want to do but hope so....

I have a page with a table of users that are grouped by product.

So:
    Customer XYZ

```
Product A
User 1
User 2

Product B
User 1
```

I would like to use the IconTabBar to allow users to see everything or to see only a particular product (A or B). My question is, can the IconBar and filtering be created dynamically? For instance, every customer does not necessarily have more than one product. So I want to be able to receive the possible products from a json call and then only show icons for the returned products.

My XML file is currently laid out like the following (leaving out some of the code to make it easier to see):

```
<Shell>
   <Page title="{/columnValue} Details" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="goBack">
    <ObjectHeader>
    </ObjectHeader>
        <IconTabBar>
             <items>
                  <IconTabFilter showAll="true" count="{/custData/cust/prodcnt}" text="Products" keys="All">
                         <Table inset="false" items="{ path:'/columnData', sorter: {        path: 'productName', descending: false, group: true } }">
                            <columns> 
                                      //column headings definition is here             
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                  /// column values defined
                            </items>
                         </Table>
                 </IconTabFilter>
             </items>
      </IconTabBar>
  </Page>
</Shell>
```

In 'custdata' I have (as shown) product counts (how many the customer has) and the products are stored in custdata/prod (an array). So I would like to create separate icons for tabs/filters for the products. Can I add them so they are created dynamically as the page is displayed (since each customer may have more or less than another customer)? The examples I have seen seem to be hard coding possible tabs/filters so I don't know if it is possible to do what I would like to do. I hope so because it would really help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be possible to do this.

The items-aggregation has to be bound to the data of the model and then it should be adjusted.

Here an example:

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
model.setData(
{
    filter: [
        { icon: "sap-icon://hint", text: 'hint'},
        { icon: "sap-icon://comment", text: 'comment'},
        { icon: "sap-icon://attachment", text: 'attachment'},
        { icon: "sap-icon://history", text: 'history'},
    ]
});

var iconTabBar = new sap.m.IconTabBar("iconTabBar", {
    expandable: true,
    expanded :true,
});

iconTabBar.setModel(model, "itbModel"); 
iconTabBar.bindAggregation("items", "itbModel>/filter", new sap.m.IconTabFilter({icon: "{itbModel>icon}", text:"{itbModel>text}"}));
```

Does this help you?

Comment: thank you. I will give it a try. Would I change the XML any or just add that code to the controller? I would think, if I understand what to do correctly, after I get my data I could add your code in for when the screen is initialized. I am wondering if I should add an ID or if any icon bars are on the screen, wouldn't they all be changed?

Comment: How can I add IconTabSeparators in between?

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to declare this binding in the XML view. :-(